How do I cancel terms involving $\delta$? I am trying to find the asymptotic series for the integral below via divide and conquer method.
My question is to find the first two terms of an asymptotic series as $ \epsilon \to 0 $ for the integral $ L(\epsilon) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+\epsilon} \,dx $ by the divide and conquer method.
Started by choosing $ \delta $ such that $ 0 \ll \epsilon \ll \delta \ll 1 $ and writing $ L(\epsilon) = \int_0^\delta \frac{1}{x+\epsilon} \,dx + \int_\delta^1\frac{1}{x+\epsilon} \,dx $.
For the first integral, setting $ x = \epsilon u $ allows us to easily obtain $ \int_0^\delta \frac{1}{x+\epsilon} \,dx = \ln(1+\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}) $.
For the second integral, noting that $ x + \epsilon = x(1+\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}) $ allows us to use a binomial expansion to simply get that $ \int_\delta^1 \frac{1}{x+\epsilon} \,dx = -\ln(\delta) + \epsilon - \frac{\epsilon}{\delta} + O(\epsilon^2\delta^{-2}) $.
Now here is my question: When we add these integral results together, all terms containing $ \delta $ are supposed to cancel out. My solutions say that you need to 'simplify' the first integral solution. Which leads to rewriting $ \ln(1+\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}) $ as $ \ln(\delta) - \ln(\epsilon) + \frac{\epsilon}{\delta} + O(\epsilon^2\delta^{-2}) $. How? I can't get this...
After I can understand this, summing the integral solutions together gives the correct final answer.

$$
L(\epsilon)=\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{x+\epsilon}dx=\int_0^{1/\epsilon}\frac{1}{y+1}dy=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)
$$
And then, by applying the Taylor series expansion to $\ln(1+\epsilon)$, you get:
$$L(\epsilon) =-\ln(\epsilon)+\ln(1+\epsilon)=-\ln(\epsilon)+\epsilon-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)$$
